# WPF user control not being visible on Visibility property change

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

Firstly I have a MVVM application whose main WPF Window contains many grid embedded and nested.

In one of these grids I have placed a user control to overlap the entire grid content as below:

**View (Main WPF Window)**:

```
<controls:UCBusy  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="12" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"                                  
                  Visibility="{Binding Path=WaitMessageVisibility}" 
                  Width="auto" Height="auto"/>
```

In **view model** I have defined the property bound:

```
   private Visibility _waitMessageVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

   public Visibility WaitMessageVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _waitMessageVisibility;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_waitMessageVisibility == value) return;
            _waitMessageVisibility = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("WaitMessageVisibility");
        }
    }
```

As you can see by default the visibility is set to Visible.

So my user control (spiner with message text on the right) should be visible but instead it is not being visible. What am I doing wrong? In order to make user control visible I set Panel.ZIndex to a higher value (100) when user control is visible using a ControlTemplate Trigger. See below.

**User Control**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Apps.WPF.Demo.Controls.UCBusy"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="FilledColor" A="255" B="222" R="176" G="196"/>
        <Color x:Key="UnfilledColor" A="0" B="222" R="176" G="196"/>           

        <Style x:Key="BusyAnimationStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation0" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation1" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation2" BeginTime="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation3" BeginTime="00:00:00.6" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation4" BeginTime="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation5" BeginTime="00:00:01.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation6" BeginTime="00:00:01.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation7" BeginTime="00:00:01.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
                            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">                                                                
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />

                                <Trigger.EnterActions>                                    
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation0}" x:Name="Storyboard0" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation1}" x:Name="Storyboard1"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation2}" x:Name="Storyboard2"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation3}" x:Name="Storyboard3"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation4}" x:Name="Storyboard4"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation5}" x:Name="Storyboard5"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation6}" x:Name="Storyboard6"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation7}" x:Name="Storyboard7"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard0"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard2"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard3"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard4"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard5"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard6"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard7"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                            <Grid>
                                <Canvas Height="60" Width="60">
                                    <Canvas.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#009B9B9B" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </Canvas.Resources>

                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse0" Canvas.Left="1.75" Canvas.Top="21"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Canvas.Top="7" Canvas.Left="6.5"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" Canvas.Left="20.5" Canvas.Top="0.75"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse3" Canvas.Left="34.75" Canvas.Top="6.75"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse4" Canvas.Left="40.5" Canvas.Top="20.75" />
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse5" Canvas.Left="34.75" Canvas.Top="34.5"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse6" Canvas.Left="20.75" Canvas.Top="39.75"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse7" Canvas.Top="34.25" Canvas.Left="7" />
                                    <Ellipse Width="39.5" Height="39.5" Canvas.Left="8.75" Canvas.Top="8" Visibility="Hidden"/> 

                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=WaitMessageText}" 
                                           FontSize="17"
                                           Canvas.Left="60.5" Canvas.Top="11.5"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                </Canvas>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>   

    <Control Style="{StaticResource BusyAnimationStyle}" />

</UserControl>
```

Comment: `<Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">` in the `Control` Style does not react on the Visibility of the `UserControl`. And why would you change the ZIndex of a Control in the Content of a UserControl. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clemens This user control is being used in other parts/areas of the WPF main window at the same time. I change user control visibility in each case through the WaitMessageVisibility property on view model. I set ZIndex in the user control content because I want to avoid defining a one property more in view model to change it.

Comment: @Clemens  I want to use only one view model property to accomplish it so when changing user control visibility through WaitMessageVisibility, user control visibility and Panel.ZIndex are updated at once and no need to update per separate both properties in view model. I set Panel.ZIndex to a higher value to make control overlap the grid content. Changing only user control visibility to true is not working the overlapping feature.

Comment: @Clemens Also instead of <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True"> I have tried <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"> but it does not work.

Comment: All that won't work. Setting the ZIndex of the Control child of the UserControl has no effect on the UserControl itself. You should instead create and apply a Style that acts on the UserControl, not the child Control.

Comment: I usually just put any spinner last in the xaml and hence on top of anything else. Bind it's visibility and default to collapsed so it's not covering everything in the designer.

Comment: @Andy Yes, putting spinner last in the xaml sequence make it remain on top of anything but in my case spinner control should overlap the entire grid except the first row of the grid (Sorry for not mentioning it in the post). When app launches by default spiner should be on top and hiding the grid except the first row. Then depending on the conditions, there are times that I need to collapse the spiner and make grid rows visible. So hence I use a view model property for setting the visibility (in combination with Panel.ZIndex) of the spiner and make it visible/collapsed.

Comment: If you set grid.row="1" grid.rowspan="10" then the spinner wouldn't cover the first row (0).

Comment: @Andy as said to Clemens in one of my comments, I would like to use only one view model property (Visibility) and avoid using two (One for setting visibility and another one for Panel.ZIndex). I often update spiner visibility from view model so I do not want to set two properties each time. I think setting Visibility is enough, and Panel.ZIndex will take a value of another depending on the Visibility I set. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Then put the spinner last. Put it in row 1 onwards. And bind visibility.

Comment: @Andy It seems that putting spinner last works. Then only setting it to Visible or Collapsed through the  view model property bound to user control Visibility property is enough. No need to use Panel.ZIndex. Thx!